# Populate database table with Laravel Faker from pre-populated table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, factory, faker

I want to populate a table with listings of car offers with dummy data.

The specific is that I want the make and model to be from a table already created in the database. Also the listing's title to be *Make* and *Model*. My code is this, but I assume it is totally wrong:

```php
public function definition()
{
    $id = DB::table('cars')->select('id')->inRandomOrder()->first();
    $make = DB::table('cars')->where('id', $id)->select('make')->first();
    $model = DB::table('cars')->where('id', $id)->select('model')->first();

    return [
        'title' => $make . " " . $model,
        'make' => $make,
        'model' => $model,
        'year' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1950, 2021),
        'slug' => $this->faker->word(),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query builder in Laravel returns an object representing the database model when you fetch with `first()`

You should access the attributes when you're setting them as other model attributes

```php
return [
    'title' => $make->make . " " . $model->model,
    'make' => $make->make,
    'model' => $model->model,
    'year' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1950, 2021),
    'slug' => $this->faker->word(),
];
```

### Note

The answer above only fixes the issue in the **current** code

The correct implementation would be to create models (if don't exist already) and link them with relationships through foreign keys and then attach them together in a seeder

The factory should only contain a clear and clean definition of fake data